# How to map a MFC dialog box to different help ids?

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a Dialog box CMyDialogBox which have help button.
I have mapped that help button to required helpid.

Question rises when I have following requirement: when I create following instances, help button should be mapped with different help.

```
CMyDialogBox mesg1;  // help should map to 123.htm
CMyDialogBox mesg2;  // help should map to 124.htm
CMyDialogBox mesg3;  // help should map to 125.htm
```

but dialog box has one help button mapped to one help content.
How can I map to multiple help id?

What I tried:
I tried to change dialog id of dialog box on `initdailog()` function using `Setntrldlg()`
but no result.

Answer (score 1):

I think you were close, but probably should have called `SetHelpID` rather than `SetDlgCtrlID`.

This question is a couple years old, so for the benefit of others who come to this question, here is how to do it. Assuming the decision of which help page to choose can be decided during `OnInitDialog`, and assuming you're using the HTML Help Compiler tools in the way it seems like you're "supposed to" use them:

1. Define IDs in the `resource.h` file, especially so the `makehm` utility sees them, to generate "H" versions.
2. In `OnInitDialog` call `SetHelpID` with one of these IDs, depending on the mode of the dialog, or whatever condition it is that requires the different help pages. Even though it's called `SetHelpID`, it takes a regular ID, since the "H"-prefixed IDs don't exist in the application.
3. In the Help files, set up the "H" versions of the IDs to map to the other HTML files.
4. If you're using a dialog template, and are not using it as one of your help IDs, you may want to continue to map it to a help page anyway, in case `SetHelpID` doesn't get called for one of your alternate IDs (maybe there's an exception or something, for example).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add a CString variable to CMyDialogBox and initialize it when construct the DialogBox.Like this: CMyDialogBox mesg1("123.htm");

Comment: intialization we can do but how can i map help button to 123.htm as every dailog idis mapped with a single help.

Comment: @Suri,why you must map help button to 123.htm?why not try this:  void CMyDialogBox::OnBnClickedHelp()
{
 //show m_page(eg:123.htm)
}

Comment: Because F1 should also invoke help. and as per microsoft to add help we have to follow steps in the link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2chd03xy(v=vs.80).aspx